# Constant Elasticity of Substitution (CES) estimation

Tags: r, windows

I am going to estimate the coefficients (values) of capital, labor, and energy via CES production function. I calculated the values of rho, rho_1, lambda etc via `CesEst` commands.

```
library(micEconCES)
cesCalc(xNames2, data = DATA1, coef(gamma,lambda, delta_1, delta,rho_1, rho), nested= TRUE)
```

> "Error: object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable"

But I am unable to find beta coefficients of these three independent variables (like: k, l, e) via `CesCalc` and I have time series data.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get the best possible help, can you explain your issue in a bit more detail and tell us what programming language you are using? What have you tried so far and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i am using "r"......i  calculated elasticity of substitution between energy , capital and labor. i did this with various methods like "NM" and Grid search method etc.  but i am unable to calculate the coefficients of labor , capital and energy. many studies did this via "cesCalc".

Comment: OK, I'm not an R expert, it would help if you could edit your question to show a small sample of your code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: o thanks a lot i type this command.....> cesCalc(xNames2, data = DATA1, coef(gamma,lambda, delta_1, delta,rho_1, rho), nested= TRUE)....but response is ............
"Error: object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable".....way out ?